# iMacros Firefox error: "unterminated string literal"

Tags: javascript, firefox, web-scraping, syntax-error, imacros

I am trying to run the following *iMacros* script:

my-imacro.iim

```
URL GOTO=https://my/json/file.json
TAG POS=1 TYPE=HTML ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXTALL
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s")
PROMPT {{!VAR1}}
```

The content at `https://my/json/file.json` looks like the following:

https://my/json/file.json

```
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": "baz"
  }
}
```

After running it, I expect to see an alert box popup with the content of the file `file.json`.

But instead, I the script terminates before completing with the following error message:

error.msg

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal, line 3 (Error code: -1001)
```

What is the error in my code? And how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be caused by the file.json data object containing a carriage return in one or more property value strings. When I test objects that do not have a carriage return, I observe the expected behavior.

The solution was to remove carriage returns at the server serving file.json with the following line of code:

file.json.server

```
var s=e.postData.contents.replace(/\n/g,"");
```